# Finding two primes $p,q$ such that $(p^2 + 1)(q^2 + 1) = n^2 + 1$

Tags: number-theory, congruences

**Find all the positive integers *p,q,n* such that *p,q* are primes and also $$(p^2 + 1)(q^2 + 1) = n^2 + 1$$.**

We know that pair squares are all divisible by 4 (because they have two or more times 2 as factor), so I squared the possible residues of 4.
$$(4k)^2 = 16k^2 = 4k$$
$$(4k+1)^2 = 16k^2 + 8k + 1 = 4k+1$$
$$(4k+2)^2 = 16k^2 + 16k + 4 = 4k$$
$$(4k+3)^2 = 16k^2 + 24k + 9 = 4k+1$$

So, every squared odd number has residue 1 when it's divided by 4.
We can notice that $n^2 + 1$ has residue 1 or 2.
Let's suposse $p$ and $q$ are both odd numbers, then
$ (p^2 + 1)(q^2 + 1) $
Has to be divisible by 4 (because both factors let residue 2), and that doesn't make sense.
So, $p$ or $q$ (it doesn't matter) has to be pair, an the only pair prime is 2. Then we have 
$$5(q^2 +1) = n^2 + 1$$

I found $$5(3^2 + 1) = 7^2 + 1$$
but i don't know if they're the only 3 numbers. So i'm wondering to know how to prove that they're, and if they aren't wich are the others (and again, how to prove that they're the only) using the method i did or another (but not that complicated)

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have to solve $p^2+p^2 q^2+q^2 = n^2$. If both $p$ and $q$ are odd, the LHS is $\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, hence it cannot be a square. It follows that the only solutions are given by $p=2$ and 
$$ 5q^2+4=n^2 $$
whose solutions [depend on Fibonacci numbers](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/nti/chap5.pdf) of the form $F_{2m}$. The only Fibonacci number of the form $F_{2m}$ that is also a prime is $F_4=3$ (due to $F_{2n}=F_n L_n$), hence the only solutions are
$$ (p,q,n)\in\{(2,3,7),(3,2,7)\}.$$

Comment: How do you know the solutions are the Fibbonacci numbers? (i opened the pdf but i didn't get it, i'm not that good at  number theory, can you please try to explain a little?

Comment: @Pulie: that is a well-known topic. The solution of Pell's equations $5n^2\pm 4=m^2$ are given by Fibonacci numers. That also follows from the general theory of Pell's equations.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Identification